# transposing data based on column value using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, transpose

I have web traffic data for a different channel. I want to transpose based on the channel name and get multiple time series.

```
day    main_channel visits  CR
11/2/2022   a   443645  1.248513488
11/2/2022   b   382870  3.441750617
11/2/2022   c   51249   0.315164766
11/1/2022   a   390267  2.725545677
11/1/2022   b   15361   0.478254073
11/1/2022   c   450734  1.513615502
```

I would like to have only a single date and transpose values in new columns.

```
day         a_visits    b_visits    c_visits    a_CR    b_CR    c_CR
11/2/2022   443645  382870  51249   1.248513488 3.441750617 0.315164766
11/1/2022   390267  15361   450734  2.725545677 0.478254073 1.513615502
```

Can someone help me here please? :)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF using pandas are fine. you could import your data as csv

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df = df.pivot_table(columns='main_channel', index='day', values=['visits','CR'])
df.columns = ['_'.join(reversed(col)) for col in df.columns.values]
```

[image]

Comment: btw, your data does not correspond to your expected output,

Comment: Thank you, it solved my issue and got to learn something new :)

Comment: glad that it helped, you could as well do without pandas, but this way is more cleaner, less line of code. you could as well edit and add pandas tags at your question if you want.

Comment: absolutely, much simpler and easy to understand. I have added pandas tag :) Thanks again!